# 1Password passkey no rawClientDataJSON

Tags: swift, ios17, passkey, 1password

iOS 17 support third party password manager such as 1Password to store and use passkey.

For iCloud passkey, it is able to obtain `rawClientDataJSON` from `ASAuthorizationPlatformPublicKeyCredentialAssertion / ASAuthorizationPlatformPublicKeyCredentialRegistration` and pass to server.

However, the `rawClientDataJSON` is empty when using 1Password passkey.

Anyone know how to get `rawClientDataJSON` value from third party passkey manager.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this issue and decided to contact 1Password considering I did not see anything weird on my end. They replied with `Our team is aware of this issue, and believes a fix may be available in iOS 17.1 or an upcoming developer beta of iOS 17.1`. Lo and behold, when I updated an iPhone to the beta version of iOS 17.1 it did actually work. So for now it seems we simply have to wait until Apple rolls out this update.

Comment: Thanks for your information. Finally, I tried to fix by my side to create the client json data locally